# javafx : How to remove or hide a ComboBox scrollbar?

Tags: combobox, javafx, scrollbar

I've a checkbox that contains 5 items when they're displayed a verticall scrollbar appears, I want to remove it or at least hide it, anyone knows how?

I tryed this but it seems to fail (exception error)

```
Node scrollBar = myComboBox.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");  
        scrollBar.setOpacity(0);
```

and this doesn't do anything too `myComboBox.setVisibleRowCount(value);`

here's an example that shows the scrollbar

package learningjavafx;

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LearnJavafx extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
        //scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        ComboBox userComboBox = new ComboBox();
        grid.add(userComboBox, 1, 1);

        userComboBox.getItems().addAll("jacob.smith@example.com",
                                       "emma.jones@example.com",
                                       "michael.brown@example.com",
                                       "MarioBross@example.com",
                                       "ethan.Williams.Isabella.Johnson.Rodregez@example.com");

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        scenetitle.setId("welcome-text");
        actiontarget.setId("actiontarget");
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add
        (LearnJavafx.class.getResource("LearningJavaFx.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean `ComboBox`?

Comment: If you are certain your items will stay 5 you can also try `ChoiceBox`

Comment: @James_D my bad :p yes  Combobox , I dont know why i wrote checkbox ....

Comment: @Phantomazi is there any other way to remove that scrollbar without changing to a choicebox, I may be need to add other items soon so I dont really want to change it.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve")? When I ran a simple test with five items in a combo box I did not see a scrollbar.

Comment: @James_D done, u'll notice the scrollbar appears the 1st time but when you click second time to see the items it desappear and  then appears ..

Comment: @James_D the scrollbar appears when the item string is very long I think

Comment: I still don't see a scrollbar.... But did you mean "vertical" or "horizontal"?

Comment: @James_D vertical scrollbar

Comment: @James_D when i run the example that i posted and click on the combobox i see the scrollbar ( when the menu is shown ) when i click 2nd time the scrollbar disappears ... I dont know  why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```css
.scroll-bar: vertical *.increment-button,
.scroll-bar: vertical *.decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
    
.scroll-bar: vertical *.increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar: vertical *.decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
    
.scroll-bar: horizontal *.increment-button,
.scroll-bar: horizontal *.decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
    
.scroll-bar: horizontal *.increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar: horizontal *.decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
```